# Вставка картинки в collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicollectionview

У меня есть кастомная ячейка с xib’ом. В xib я вставил только UIImageView.
Задаю размер ячейки через UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, чтобы на каждой строчке было по 3 ячейки и вроде все получается правильно. Но когда я начинаю вставлять в UIImageView картинку размер ячейки увеличивается в несколько раз и ячейка становится огромной т.е до вставки картинки ячейки отображаются все правильно.
Не понимаю какие констрейнты и настройки мне установить для uiimageview в моем cell xib’е.
Пробовал ставить top,left,right,bottom, aspect fit и clip to bounds, но это не помогает.
Что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело здесь скорее всего не в констрейнтах, если они установлены правильно. Попробуйте данный трюк

```
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.estimatedItemSize = .zero
```

Работает с лейаутом по 3 ячейки в ряд

```
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let itemSize = (screenWidth / 3) - 10

        return CGSize(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло, а вы не подскажете еще как сделать например если у меня фотография не квадратная. Сейчас, если она не 1:1, то у ячейки остаются края. Как сделать чтобы фотография при отображении ячейки обрезалась в формат 1:1

Comment: стоило лишь aspect fill поставить)